# How to deal with non-normal data? Tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, nonparametric, group-differences

I have a database of a breaking news (tweets, timed events) and i need to find if there are significant differences in the coverage of the events by different media outlets (MOs) with different clasifications (who owns them, their ideology, and so on).

In other words: has MO_x dealt with an event (statistically) significantly later than MO_y?

The issue is that my sample does not have a normal distribution so i imagine ANOVA wont work for me, then i was wondering, which would be the best test to evaluate significant differences betwen those groups given time-based events...

Comment: Data is neither parametric or non-parametric. These terms apply to the method you use to fit a model. I think what you mean is that your data doesn't fit well to a normal distribution. You should also be aware that there are other parametric families of distributions besides the normal family.

Comment: You can use the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test of the difference between the the median of the two groups.

Comment: ANOVA  is somewhat forgiving for non-normality, so the question is how non-normal?  Next, there are myriad methods but each answer a different question. For example, Cramer---von Mises can be used as a two sample test to see if two distributions are different and there are many other tests, so which is most appropriate depends on *exactly* what is in the data and *exactly* what is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have three different kinds of media outlets and that delays in coverage are exponential.

None of the most common tests is ideal: (a) A standard ANOVA would not be idea because data are not normal and because variances are not the same (if populations differ). A Welch ANOVA test (`oneway.test` in R) would accommodate to differences in variances.

(b) Such an ANOVA on ranks would help to 'tame' the skewness of exponential data. (Taking logs of data, not shown here, might be another option.)

(c) A Kruskal-Wallis test would not be ideal because (for exponential data)
differences in delays are more about scale than location.

Nevertheless, any of the three tests might be useful. (There are other options, which others on this site may choose to discuss.)

Here are summaries and boxplots for some data simulated in R. In R, the
parameter for an exponential distribution is the rate (inverse of mean):

```
set.seed(611)
x1 = rexp(10, 1);  x2 = rexp(15, 1.5);  x3 = rexp(20, .5)
summary(x1); sd(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.2002  0.3724  0.8494  1.0129  1.3879  2.3038 
[1] 0.7610589      # SD Group 1
summary(x2); sd(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.01912 0.08289 0.65741 0.60690 0.91206 2.30936 
[1] 0.6447723
summary(x3); sd(x3)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.08635 0.66001 1.28122 1.96687 3.19834 7.23186 
[1] 1.851478
x = c(x1, x2, x3);  gp=as.factor(rep(1:3, c(10,15,20)))
boxplot(x ~ gp, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

```
oneway.test(x ~ gp)

        One-way analysis of means (not assuming equal variances)

data:  x and gp
F = 4.8001, num df = 2.000, denom df = 24.379, p-value = 0.01747

oneway.test(rank(x)~gp)

        One-way analysis of means (not assuming equal variances)

data:  rank(x) and gp
F = 5.0117, num df = 2.000, denom df = 24.671, p-value = 0.01491

kruskal.test(x ~ gp)

        Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  x by gp
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 8.8826, df = 2, p-value = 0.01178
```

With some precautions against false discovery (such as Bonferroni confidence levels), Welch two-sample t tests and two-sample Wilcoxon tests could be used
for ad hoc investigations of patterns of differences.

For example, here are *ad.hoc* tests comparing the second and third (fake) 'media outlets' in my data:

```
t.test(x2, x3)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x2 and x3
t = -3.0477, df = 24.763, p-value = 0.005418
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -2.2794258 -0.4405098
 sample estimates:
 mean of x mean of y 
 0.6068979 1.9668657 

 wilcox.test(x2,x3)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  x2 and x3
W = 64, p-value = 0.003435
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```